# Custom Title bar in Android

Tags: android, titlebar

I have create a custom title bar, It contains a TextView and label. i have added this to an activity as follows

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.windowtitle);
```

But now i want to display current time in the textview inside the titlebar.

How can this be done?

Comment: Create a TextView in your title to display the time, then create a `TimerTask` that will run once a minute and update the content of this TextView with the current time.

Comment: Actually I want to know how can i access the textview in the custom titlebar

Comment: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

Comment: Current time in a title bar? Leave the notification bar available (no full screen) and you have time at the usual place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get text view like this.create a `mytitle.xml` layout with `textview` and then add this code it will work..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

  if ( customTitleSupported ) {
      getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
  }

  final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
  if ( myTitleText != null ) {         
      myTitleText.setText(" TITLE  ");     
  }
}
```

Comment: are you added mytitle.xml layout in the layout folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17803/discussion-between-pramod-j-george-and-rajareddy-polamreddy)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.windowtitle, null, true);
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
txtdate.setText(c.getTime());
```

Comment: This is the code for inflating a layout into another.  though it is not worked for me , thanks for this